# Cant commit a folder: error: pathspec 'message' did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, ubuntu, github

My SO is ubuntu 18.04.

I have a project already created in /opt/lampp/htdocs/projects/myProject.

I wanted to implement version control on it, so i did `git init` in that directory.

But then i did `git add .` and `git commit -m 'Your message here'` and i added a folder that i dont want to push to the remote repo. So i did `git reset`
 and `rm -rf .git && git init` .

After that i added only the folder that i want : `git add frontEnd`
Then: `git commit frontEnd "front end commit"`

And now appears error:

```
pathspec 'front end commit' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

( i didn't made any pull nor push yet)

Comment: Look carefully at the two `git commit` commands you wrote above. Is there a flag missing from the one that isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Your git commit command is not correct. Try following command

```
git commit -m "front end commit"
```